# How to lex a here-string in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to figure out how to lex something like HERE-STRING using Racket lexer tools. For example:

```
string(END-MARKER)
any text goes here except the end marker
END-MARKER
```

All of this should be lexed as a token with the value "\nany text goes here except the end marker\n". I need a way to somehow capture END-MARKER. I think there is some way to achieve it using lexer macros, but I haven't found any good documentation on how to use them.

Unfortunately I don't see any approach now so I could not include any code here. It should be something like:

```
#lang racket

(require parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre)

(define-lex-abbrev here-string
  (:: "string(" <...>))
```